# How would one call std::forward on all arguments in a variadic function?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I was just writing a generic object factory and using the boost preprocessor meta-library to make a variadic template (using 2010 and it doesn't support them). My function uses rval references and `std::forward` to do perfect forwarding and it got me thinking...when C++0X comes out and I had a standard compiler I would do this with real variadic templates.  How though, would I call `std::forward` on the arguments?

```
template <typename ...Params>
void f(Params... params) // how do I say these are rvalue reference?
{
    y(std::forward(...params)); //? - I doubt this would work.
}
```

Only way I can think of would require manual unpacking of ...params and I'm not quite there yet either. Is there a quicker syntax that would work?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You would do:

```
template <typename ...Params>
void f(Params&&... params)
{
    y(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}
```

The `...` is a [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) and pretty much says "take what's on the left, and for each template parameter, unpack it accordingly."

For example, `f<int, float&>` instantiated looks like:

```cpp
void f<int, float&>(int&& params_0, float& params_1)
{
    y(std::forward<int>(params_0), std::forward<float&>(params_1));
}
```

Comment: Add to that how the parameters should be passed. I think tutorials show `void f(Params&& ...params)`

Comment: Please explain the motivation of the choice of rvalue reference && (instead of & reference or just by value depending on situation)

Comment: @DavidJ I've taken the motivation as baked into the question. See however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward

Comment: I really can not get the idea behind where ... should go

Comment: @DavidJ The && in this case is not an rvalue reference but a forwarding (or universal) reference. When used with templates it can bind to any reference type. https://blog.petrzemek.net/2016/09/17/universal-vs-forwarding-references-in-cpp/

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092534/syntax-of-with-parameter-pack-expansion-using-stdforward