# Forwarding variadic list of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, perfect-forwarding

Both of the following code compiles and performs as expected, are they different?

```
template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto time_function(T&& func, U&& ...args)
{
   std::cout << "timing" << std::endl;
   auto val = std::forward<T>(func)(std::forward<U...>(args...));
   std::cout << "timing over" << std::endl;
   return val;
}

template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto time_function(T&& func, U&& ...args)
{
   std::cout << "timing" << std::endl;
   auto val = std::forward<T>(func)(std::forward<U>(args)...);
   std::cout << "timing over" << std::endl;
   return val;
}
```

Looking at SO [How would one call std::forward on all arguments in a variadic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821223/how-would-one-call-stdforward-on-all-arguments-in-a-variadic-function), second seems to be recommended, but doesn't the first do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same. They are the same in the case that the arity of `args` is 1 or 0. otherwise it will fail to compile, consider..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto time_function_1(T&& func, U&& ...args)
{

    std::cout<<"timing"<<std::endl;
    auto val = std::forward<T>(func)(std::forward<U...>(args...));
    std::cout<<"timing over"<<std::endl;
    return val;
}

    template<typename T, typename ...U>
auto time_function_2(T&& func, U&& ...args)
{

    std::cout<<"timing"<<std::endl;
    auto val = std::forward<T>(func)(std::forward<U>(args)...);
    std::cout<<"timing over"<<std::endl;
    return val;
}



int f (int){return 0;}

int y (int,int){return 0;}

int main() {
    time_function_1(f,1);
    time_function_2(f,1);

    time_function_1(y,1,2); // fail
    time_function_2(y,1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/qPLpWt)

for the failing case `std::forward<U...>(args...)` expands to `forward<int, int>(int&, int&)` and will fail to compile.

`std::forward<U>(args)...` expands to `std::forward<int>(int&),std::forward<int>(int&)`

Comment: so forward can take only a single template argument?

Comment: yes, correct, see here -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Comment: since you are passing a temporary, shouldn't it expand to forward<int, int>(int&&, int&&), are am I misunderstanding

Comment: Its a named temporary now. inside of time_function the ints are all part of the named parameter pack called args. This is the whole point in std::forward. it will transform it back in this case to int&&

Comment: Ah yes, as for the template parameter type, shouldn't it be int&&? To my understanding, std::forward knows whether to cast or not based on the template inference type

Comment: This might clear up whats happening.The important thing in the example below is that U is not just 'int' in each case, if its an lvalue it will be int& and reference collapsing rules apply https://ideone.com/cfK0cb. This should give you a feel for how 'std::forward knows whether to cast or not'