# Syntax of '...' with Parameter Pack Expansion using std::forward

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, perfect-forwarding

In C++, it seems that a parameter may be normally expanded with `...` directly after the parameter pack's name. For example,

```cpp
template <class... Tys>
void function(Tys... params) {
    function(params...);
}
```

However, when using `std::forward`, the `...` goes seemingly *after* the parameter pack's name. For example,

```cpp
template <class... Tys>
void function(Tys... params) {
    function(std::forward<Tys>(params)...); // The '...' is outside the parenthesis of 'params'
}
```

My question is why is there a difference? Why is the following code incorrect?

```cpp
template<class... Tys>
void function(Tys... params) {
    function(std::forward<Tys>(params...));
}
```

At what point in the parameter pack expanded? I probably am not fully understanding how `std::forward` works or how it forwards arguments perfectly.

I appreciate any answers!

Comment: Related reading for understanding forwarding: [Advantages of using forward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/10239789)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `...` applies to the thing on its left.

- `function(params...)`

  expands to

  `function(param1, param2, ..., paramN)`.
- `function(std::forward<Tys>(params)...)`

  expands to

  `function(std::forward<Tys1>(param1), std::forward<Tys2>(param2), ..., std::forward<TysN>(paramN))`
- `function(std::forward<Tys>(params...))`

  expands to

  `function(std::forward<Tys>(param1, param2, ..., paramN))`